# SetWinEventHook - Dll injection?

Tags: dll, hook, internals

I try to inject a dll to a process through SetWinEventHook.

```
SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_TEXTSELECTIONCHANGED, EVENT_OBJECT_TEXTSELECTIONCHANGED, NULL , HandleWinEvent, iexploreId , 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT))
```

The hooked function is called, but I don't see that the dll is loaded to the hooked process. 
Doesn't SetWinEventHook implement loading the dll to the hooked process?

Thanks!

Comment: No, that's SetWindowsHookEx().  The one nobody can ever get going.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT` parameter, which means: The callback function is not mapped into the address space of the process that generates the event.

More details Here: Out-of-Context Hook Functions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Out-of-context hook functions are located in the client's address space, whether it is in the code body or in a DLL.

Out-of-context hook functions are not mapped into the server's address space.

When an event is triggered, the parameters for the hook function are marshaled across process boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Inject your DLL in target process using whatever method you feel suitable, and then use 
WINEVENT_INCONTEXT as last parameter in SetWinEventHook function.